# This.router.navigate does not call component constructor - Angular 5 / AWS Amplify

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, routes, angular5, aws-amplify

I'm having trouble with a sign in method I am trying to do with AWS Amplify.  It has multi-factor authentication and when the MFA is successful I am trying to route the app to another route/component via router.navigate().

When I do this the constructor does not run.  This is where I am subscribed to the Amplify authState with dependency injection.  It subscribes to the authState and brings in the user information.  It does not work with the initial success and routing via router.navigate().  If I refresh the page everything works fine because it calls the constructor.

I tried using ngZone.run() but that didn't work for me either.  Here is my code.

Multi-factor authentication check for signing in - Sign-In Component

```
submitMFA() {
    console.log(this.mfaCode);
    if (this.mfaType == 'SMS_MFA') {
      Auth.confirmSignIn(this.user,this.mfaCode, 'SMS_MFA')
        .then(user => {
          this.loginSuccess();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.loginError(err);
        });
    } else {
      Auth.confirmSignIn(this.user,this.mfaCode, 'SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA')
        .then(user => {
          this.loginSuccess();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.loginError(err);
        });
    }
  }

  loginSuccess() {
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(this.user);
    this.resetMFA();
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

Home Component I am trying to navigate to:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AmplifyService } from 'aws-amplify-angular';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
var QRCode = require('qrcode');

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  userGroup: string = "none";
  user: any = null
  preferredMFA: string = null;
  totpSetup: boolean = false

  constructor(private amplifyService: AmplifyService, private ngZone: NgZone) {

    this.amplifyService.authStateChange$
      .subscribe(authState => {
        if (authState.state === 'signedIn') {
          this.user = authState.user;
          console.log(this.user);

          if (authState.user.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]) {
            // This sets what group the user is in. Based on this group we set what perspectives will show.  Ex: The 'Administration' link only shows in the nav bar for users in the Admins group
            this.userGroup = authState.user.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"][0];
          } else {
            console.log("No usergroup found");
          }

          this.preferredMFA = this.user.preferredMFA;
        }
      });
  }
```

Here is my routing.ts file

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { AuthenticationComponent } from './components/authentication/authentication.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './components/not-found/not-found.component';


export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: AuthenticationComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];

export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate takes a string array, not a string.

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

Comment: I edited that thank you.  That is not what is causing the problem though I just wrote that wrong when I submitted my question.

Comment: you should post your routes file as well for troubleshooting

Comment: Added my routing.ts file.  Is this what you requested?